# how to display only the users that are on device contact list, from the database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

It's a chatting application where i only wanted to display the users from database those whose numbers are available on the users device contact list.

I have got the list of contact list but i don't know how to query the database or i even tried a work around where it displays the user information who are present but those who are not present it shows a default itemview. You can check image link for reference

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4BFR.jpg]

```
package com.example.myapplication;    
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    ImageView imageViewOfUser;

    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebasemodel, NoteViewHolder> chatAdapter;


    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    ArrayList<String> contactList;
    ArrayList<String> getcontactList;


    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        contactList = new ArrayList<String>();
        getcontactList = getContactList();
        
            Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereNotEqualTo("uid", firebaseAuth.getUid());


            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firebasemodel> allusername = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firebasemodel>().setQuery(query, firebasemodel.class).build();

            chatAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebasemodel, NoteViewHolder>(allusername) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder noteViewHolder, int i, @NonNull firebasemodel firebasemodel) {

                    for (String m : getcontactList) {
                        if (firebasemodel.getContact().equals(m)) {


                            noteViewHolder.particularusername.setText(firebasemodel.getName());
                            String uri = firebasemodel.getImage();

                            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageViewOfUser);
                            if (firebasemodel.getStatus().equals("Online")) {
                                noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                                noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setTextColor(Color.rgb(66, 133, 244));
                            } else {
                                noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                            }
                            
                            noteViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on particular user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                             //else code?
                        }
                    }
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatviewlayout, parent, false);
                    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
                }

            };

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize((true));
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            
        return view;
    }

    public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView particularusername;
        private TextView statusofuser;
        public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            particularusername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofuser);
            statusofuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusofuser);
            imageViewOfUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewofuser);
        }
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        chatAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(chatAdapter!=null){
            chatAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    
    private ArrayList<String> getContactList(){
        Cursor phones =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()){
            String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
            contactList.add(phone);
        }
        return contactList;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).